# Reading Single Excel file concurrently in java

Tags: java, multithreading, excel, jenkins, jdbc-odbc

We got this requirement while trying to run our framework from two different Jenkins jobs

Following is our code:

```
String xlsPath= System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\TestInputs\\Config.xls";
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft    Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=" +xlsPath+ ";DriverID=22;READONLY=TRUE","","");
String sql="Select  *  from [Setup$]";
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
{

    System.out.println(rs.getString(1).toString());
    System.out.println(rs.getString(2).toString());
    System.out.println(rs.getString(3).toString());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
rs.close();
st.close();
conn.close();
```

The above code working absolutely fine when we are trying to execute through multi threading concept.

But I am getting following error message if I create TWO JENKINS JOBS and running them parallely.

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

Do we have any workaround for this? so that I can execute two jobs without any issues.

NOTE: I cannot use HSSF or someother means to read my excel file. I should strictly use Database commands like I used it in the above code.

Please help !

Comment: Perhaps you could make a temporary copy of the file and pass it your driver.

Comment: Or (if UPDATE occurs), create "microservice" providing serial access to .xls behind.